# Summarise to include group by column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data

```
pt_id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
Tobacco <- c("once","twice","never", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,"Once","Twice","Quit","Once",NA,NA,"Never", NA, "Never")
Alcohol <- c("twice", "once",NA, NA, "never", NA, NA, "Once", NA, "Quit", "Twice", NA, "Once", NA, NA, "Never", "Never")
PA <- c("once",NA,"never", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,"Once",NA,"Quit","Once",NA,NA,"Never", NA, NA)
mydata <- data.frame(pt_id, Tobacco, Alcohol, PA)
mydata
```

I used the following code to get the resulting output

```
library(tidyverse)
data_summ <- mydata %>%
  group_by(pt_id) %>%
  summarise(across(Tobacco:PA, ~sum(!is.na(.)))) 

data_summ %>%
  summarise(across(Tobacco:PA, ~prop.table(.) * 100))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Tobacco Alcohol    PA
    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1    33.3    33.3  33.3
2     0      11.1   0  
3    44.4    33.3  50  
4    22.2    22.2  16.7
```

Now my problem is I want the pt_id column to appear in my output. I tried using `group_by(pt_id)` but that changed my results across other columns. How can I include the pt_id column in my output?

Desired output:

```
pt_id  Tobacco Alcohol  PA
   
1        33.3    33.3  33.3
2         0      11.1   0  
3        44.4    33.3  50  
4        22.2    22.2  16.7
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last statement, use `mutate` instead of `summarise` to keep the variable `pt_id` in the output

```
data_summ <- mydata %>%
  group_by(pt_id) %>%
  summarise(across(Tobacco:PA, ~sum(!is.na(.)))) 

data_summ %>%
  mutate(across(Tobacco:PA, ~prop.table(.) * 100))
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   pt_id Tobacco Alcohol    PA
#   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    33.3    33.3  33.3
# 2     2     0      11.1   0  
# 3     3    44.4    33.3  50  
# 4     4    22.2    22.2  16.7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
  group_by(pt_id) %>%
  summarise(across(Tobacco:PA, ~sum(!is.na(.)))) %>%
  mutate(across(Tobacco:PA, .fns = ~.x/sum(.x)*100))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  pt_id Tobacco Alcohol    PA
#  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    33.3    33.3  33.3
# 2     2     0      11.1   0  
# 3     3    44.4    33.3  50  
# 4     4    22.2    22.2  16.7
```